# Cantinue в JS

Tags: javascript

Почему пропускаются итерации поле 30? Cantinue должен же пропускать только одну.

```
<script>
function fun3() {   
        for (i = 40; i>=0; i-=5)
    {
                if (i==25)
        {
                Cantinue();
        }
            else ()
        {
            document.write(i + '<br />');
        }       
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='Вывести числа от 40 до 0 с шагом 5 пропустив 25' onclick='fun3()' />
```

Comment: посмотрите в консоль браузера, и увидите там кучу ошибок. Потому что вы написали отборный бред

Comment: **.**cantina!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function fun3() {
      for (i = 40; i >= 0; i -= 5) {
        if (i == 25) continue;
        document.write(i + '<br />');
      }
    }
```